# Update boolean value in data extension from false to true with Sql Query

Tags: query, dataextensions, data, sql

I have an existing Data Extension with attributes that contain booleans fields that are marked as false. I want to force those fields and the boolean value to now equal true.

I am wondering if there is a query I can use to update existing subscribers in the Data extension to change them from false to true?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume the columns  name is `EmailOptIn`

Try this:

```
Select
True as EmailOptIn
From DataExtensionContainingAttributes
Where
EmailOptIn = False
```

Update:

As [Adam Spriggs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) suggested, you can also use 1 for true and 0 for false

Comment: You can also use `1` for true and `0` for false.

Comment: Will update my answer

Comment: That's good to hear! if it did then community norm is to accept the answer :)